# DataWeave field referense

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I am new to Mule and I'm trying to create a payload. I looked multiple examples but I'm unable to find a solution for below scenario. I wanted to populate sampleRecord3 based on boolean value of sampleRecord2.I am keep getting error for below scenario. Any help/suggestions?

```json
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    "sampleRecord1" : "Test1",
    "sampleRecord2" :  true/false,
    "sampleRecord3" :  if(sampleRecord2==true) 5 else 10
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DataWeave each key-value in an object is independent from the others and you can not reference them. Instead you could use a local variable to reuse the same value in both places:

```js
%dw 2.0 
output application/json
---
do {
    var sampleRecord2Value=true
    ---
    {
        "sampleRecord1" : "Test1",
        "sampleRecord2" :  sampleRecord2Value,
        "sampleRecord3" :  if(sampleRecord2Value==true) 5 else 10
    }
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "sampleRecord1": "Test1",
  "sampleRecord2": true,
  "sampleRecord3": 5
}
```

Comment: Thank you @aled for the explanation ! I changed my logic and it worked fine !